# Driving from Melbourne to Sydney on the Hume Highway, where should we stop for the night?

Tags: australia, driving, road-trips, sydney, melbourne

We'll shortly be driving from Melbourne to Sydney on the Hume Highway and plan to stop for two nights en route.  We'll have a late departure from Melbourne, so the goal is to drive only a few hours the first day, drive well past the halfway point on the 2nd day, and then coast into Sydney on the third day.  All the towns and motels along the way seem to be much of a muchness, so any recommendations?  We'll have a hyperactive two-year-old in tow, which is also why we're scheduling in a lot of time for breaks, so pools, parks, playgrounds etc are a definite bonus, both in town and along the way.

And yes, we know that it would more make sense to fly or at least take "the long way" via the coast, but unfortunately we're both pressed for time *and* need to get our car to Sydney.  We've also been to Canberra already and would rather not detour, and finally, I also have it on good authority that Gundagai of "Tucker Box" fame is a dump.

Comment: As this is a 3 day trip, how much detour are you willing to suffer ? Is there a limit on how much car time per day ?

Comment: Our son gets antsy if he's stuck in a car for more than an hour while awake, and naps once for max. 2 hours in the afternoon.  So assuming breakfast - drive - break - drive - lunch - drive (nap) - break - drive - arrival, we'd prefer to spend under 5 hours/day in the car.

Comment: Sounds busy to me

Comment: Yup, it's called parenthood...  but the only other real alternative is driving at night, which we're even less keen on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd stop in Albury then Goulburn both about 3.5 hours drive and on the Hume Highway. I've visited both and Albury has some nice parks and if you're onto big things Goulburn has the Big Merino.*

Comment: And if you go to Goulburn, then visit the Paragon cafe.

Comment: In Albury I'd have to suggest the Green Zebra - great pasta café.

Comment: We had breakfast at Paragon, and it was a great 50's time warp!  Any cafe that does lambs fry (read: liver) for breakfast has a special place in my heart... and yes, they do pancakes and eggs etc if you're a wuss.